# How to sandbox code running another app (started using Process.Start)?

Tags: c#, security, resources, sandbox, appdomain

I've heard of sandboxing and how to make a simple example using `AppDomain` in .NET as in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/misc/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox

However the unsafe (or untrusted) code I execute here is run another process using `Process.Start` (or if you know another way to help limit access of the started process, please suggest). My purpose is to constrain resource access of the started process (may not be a .NET app). So for example, the started process should not be able to access any file in the current environment.

The issue here is we need a security context (provided by the current `AppDomain`) having full-trust (unrestricted) for `Process.Start` to work.
I really hope that the current partially-trusted context (before calling `Process.Start`) would be cascaded down to the started process and can help constrain the resource access as expected. But if we need a full-trust context to run `Process.Start`, then it fails right at that step.

I've run out of ideas for how to make this possible because the only way I know to run a process in .NET is using `Process.Start` but it requires full-trust context … :(

Here is the code I've tried and there is always an error being thrown right before calling `Process.Start`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ads = new AppDomainSetup();
        ads.ApplicationBase = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        var ps = new PermissionSet(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.None);
        ps.AddPermission(new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.Execution));
        var ad = AppDomain.CreateDomain("SB", null, ads, ps);

        var sb = ad.CreateInstanceAndUnwrap(typeof(Sandbox).Assembly.FullName, typeof(Sandbox).FullName) as Sandbox;

        //the code throws exception and be highlighted at this line
        sb.ExecuteUnsafeCode();

        Console.WriteLine("End!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
//the sandbox class
public class Sandbox : MarshalByRefObject
{       
    //this simple method stub is just for testing
    public void ExecuteUnsafeCode()
    {
        try
        {                
            var si = new ProcessStartInfo("someSimpleApp.exe");
            Process.Start(si);

            Console.WriteLine("Run OK!");                
        } catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SecurityException caught:\n{0}", ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The exception thrown is a `SecurityException` with a very short message of `Request fail`. The stack-trace is also too short (only 3 lines) and actually contains nothing helpful.

The bigger picture of my purpose here is to run submitted code (from user) in a sandbox so that no malicious code can harm the server. If the submitted code is some .NET lang, it would be easier because I may not have to use `Process.Start` here. But the submitted code is `Java` or unmanaged `C++`, really we have to compile it into some executable file and run it using `Process.Start`.

I hope to get some suggestions to try out, of course it's better if I have a right solution for this, thanks!

Comment: A .net AppDomain sandbox is the wrong concept here. It can only be applied to .net code running in the same process. Unmanaged code or other processes can not be uncluded in your sandbox. You could go one layer up and run the untrusted code in a virtual maschine or container.

Comment: @thehennyy I doubted about that magic of app domain sandbox. I also know of container (using docker) but at this phase we're not ready yet, VMs are too heavyweight so we cannot use them.